# Check if a read value is hex or decimal in python?

Tags: python, hex, ipv6

I'm working on a IPv6 header compressor called SCHC, and in my code I have to read a value that sometimes it's decimal, and others is hexadecimal. I'll show you an example:

```
#                  fID                 pos  dir   tv                    mo         cda

rule = {"ruleid"  : 0,
     "content" : [["IPv6.version",      1,  "bi", 6,                  "equal", "not-sent"],
                  ["IPv6.trafficClass", 1,  "bi", 0x00,               "equal", "not-sent"],
                  ["IPv6.flowLabel",    1,  "bi", 0x000000,           "ignore", "not-sent"],
                  ["IPv6.payloadLength",1,  "bi", None,               "ignore", "compute-length"],
                  ["IPv6.nextHeader",   1,  "bi", 17,                 "equal", "not-sent"],
                  ["IPv6.hopLimit",     1,  "bi", 30,                 "equal", "not-sent"],
                  ["IPv6.prefixES",     1,  "bi", 0x200104701f1209f2, "equal", "not-sent"],
                  ["IPv6.iidES",        1,  "bi", 0x000000000000000b, "equal", "not-sent"],
                  ["IPv6.prefixLA",     1,  "bi", [0xFE80000000000000,
                                                  0x2001123456789012,
                                                  0x200104701f1209f2,
                                                  0x200141d004013100],"match-mapping", "mapping-sent"],
                  ["IPv6.iidLA",        1,  "bi", 0x0000000000003682, "equal", "not-sent"],
                  ["UDP.PortES",        1,  "bi", 5684,               "equal", "not-sent"],
                  ["UDP.PortLA",        1,  "bi", 5684,               "equal", "not-sent"],
                  ["UDP.length",        1,  "bi", None,               "ignore", "compute-length"],
                  ["UDP.checksum",      1,  "bi", None,               "ignore", "compute-checksum"],
                  ["CoAP.version",      1,  "bi", 1,                  "equal", "not-sent"],
                  ["CoAP.type",         1,  "up", 0,                  "equal", "not-sent"],
                  ["CoAP.type",         1,  "dw", 2,                  "equal", "not-sent"],
                  ["CoAP.tokenLength",  1,  "bi", 1,                  "equal", "not-sent"],
                  ["CoAP.code",         1,  "up", 2,                  "equal", "not-sent"],
                  ["CoAP.code",         1,  "dw", [69, 132],          "match-mapping", "mapping-sent"],
                  ["CoAP.messageID",    1,  "bi", 0,                  "MSB(12)", "LSB"],
                  ["CoAP.token",        1,  "bi", 0x80,               "MSB(4)", "LSB"],
                  ["CoAP.Uri-Path",     1,  "up", "foo",              "equal", "not-sent"],
                  ["CoAP.Uri-Path",     2,  "up", "bar",              "equal", "not-sent"],
                  ["CoAP.Uri-Path",     3,  "up", None,               "ignore", "value-sent"],
                  ["CoAP.Content-Format",1, "dw", None,               "ignore", "value-sent"],
                  ["CoAP.Uri-Query",    1,  "up", "k=",               "MSB(16)", "LSB"],
                  ["CoAP.Option-End",   1,  "up", 0xFF,               "equal", "not-sent"]
               ]}
```

This is an example of a rule compression for SCHC. As you can see, the tv (target value) field can be sometimes an integer, a string, an array... and in the case of integers, they may have decimal or hexadecimal representation. What I want to do is rewrite in a string the value of that integer, but my problem is that when I access to that value I have no way to know if it was hex or dec.

I have already tryed many things such as regular expressions, using functions like str(tv) but it returns always in decimal unless I write str(hex(tv)), but still have the same problem that I don't know if the original value was hex or dec.

Thank you in advance, and I hope that my explanation was clear!

--- Update ---

So, if I do something like this right after the declaration of the variable "rule",

```
for line in rule['content']:
  fID,pos,di,tv,mo,cda = line
  print(line[3])
```

the output of the print will be "2306129363794528754" in the IPv6.prefixES line, instead of 0x200104701f1209f2.

The same output is done if I write "print(str(line[3])" instead.

Comment: What is the source for your data? If it's a dictionary defined in the script, such as the one you show, then there's really no way to tell if the original value was hex or int, because to Python they're the same; try `0xFF == 255` in a terminal and you'll find the answer to be `True`. Prefixing with `0x` is merely a convenience for when you're working with hex values; their in-memory representation is the same.

Comment: yes, and that's what I tryed with regular expressions, to detect if it begins with "0x", but when I call that position it always take the base 10 representation. I'll update my post now with an example

Comment: Yes Pedro. The source is the dictionary defined in the own code... So it looks like there's no fix for this?

Comment: Why do you need to know how the value was originally expressed?

Comment: Hi Chris, because I want to create C code for defining the compression rules from python to C (a kind of parser), and it could be really usefull to name constants and variables with its real notation, such as "#define IPV6_PREFIXLA_0X2001123456789012 1;"

Comment: You must think of some kind of rule that determines the difference between "numbers in decimal" and "numbers in hex". Your example shows a possible test: a larger decimal than any sane person would write (and it would not work for the smaller hex numbers in your data).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Integers in Python prefixed by `0x` are represented under the hood in just the same way as integers that aren't. This means that to Python, 0xFF is *the same* as 255, and there's no way to tell them apart; `0x` is just a convenient way to describe ints when you're working in hex base. The same goes for `0b`, the binary representation.

As such, there's no way to tell them apart as they are in your code. Try the following in a REPL:

```
>>> 0xFF == 255
True
>>> isinstance(255, int)
True
>>> isinstance(0xFF, int)
True
>>> 0xFF
255
>>> 0b11111111 == 0xFF == 255
True
```

Your regex doesn't work because the regex expects a string; when it sees your integer, it casts the int to a string but since the default representation is to cast an integer to base 10, it appears as just that: a base 10 integer.

The solution in your case would be to actually store the hex values as string and then convert them back to integers when you actually want to use them, that is:

`["IPv6.prefixES",     1,  "bi", "0x200104701f1209f2", "equal", "not-sent"],`

(note that the quotes indicate it's a string)

Or to store it as an integer as you are doing, and then get their hexadecimal representation whenever you want to show it as a hex number.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's like I expected, I should have to use them as strings if I want to do that, but it's not the ideal way...
Like I said, thanks for your answer, it's very clear ;)